# print the kth element from the list. list will be obtained by based on number present in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have some prime numbers in the array say {2, 3, 5}. I want to print the Kth number that is divisible by either of any array elements.

For example for this array list of divisible numbers can be (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16 ..). 7th in the list will be 9.

Any thoughts on logic to write the program for it?

Comment: I think your example is wrong, because `4` is also divisible by `2` so it should also be in the list. And when `4` get included 6th number become `8` instead of `9`.

Comment: oops.. i missed 4. Thanks for observation. i corrected it.

Comment: Simple logic to start with create a list up-to size **K** with the multiples of numbers present in your prime number list, like: 2's multiple are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 etc. 3's multiples are 3,6,9,12 etc. Take care of your duplicates while doing this.

Comment: Thanks for response. I just wanted to avoid creation of list as they are interested in kth position number only not in complete list. can't we make it possible without creating list?

Comment: As even enumeration of such sequences has been discussed over and again, the first and foremost task is setting a non-trivial goal: how about computing the Kth number directly, e.g. for K = googolplex? (How many numbers out of the product of your primes are part of the sequence?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easiest to just collect too many values and find the Kth.

Steps:

1. Sort your primes into an array. e.g. `primes = {2, 3, 5}`
2. Build an array of arrays, each array storing the values for the multiples:

   - We know that `primes[0] * K` is an upper bound (inclusive) on the value we want, so we can use this to bound how far to go for each.
   - In your example, this would be `2 * 6 = 12`, so we would build:

     ```
     {
         {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12},
         {3, 6, 9, 12},
         {5, 10}
     }
     ```
3. Then count out the Kth member, but watch out for duplicates.

**Updated:**

Based on your comments, you've considered this method, but don't like it.

Alternatively, don't worry about sorting your primes.  Instead, we will iterate directly through the list in the human-computable way of doing this.

1. Create an integer representing the current list index.  We'll keep going until this reaches k.
2. Create an array of zeros of the same length as the array of primes.  We'll use this to track the current multiplier for each prime.  You'll see what I mean by this in a minute.
3. To find the next item in the list, compute the least multiple of the primes, multiplying the prime by 1 + the prime's current multiplier. Keep in mind that they may have duplicates.
4. Update the prime's multipliers for the primes which divide the least multiple.

Since this is all a little abstract and using poorly defined terms, let's do a quick example of `K = 6`, `Primes = {2, 3, 5}`:

- When `index == 0`, `Multipliers = {0, 0, 0}`, we find 2 as the least multiple, so we update `Multipliers = {1, 0, 0}` and increment our index, performing the check that the index is less than the index we are looking for. (since the index is 0-based, we want `index == k - 1` or `index + 1 == k`.)
- On `index == 1`: we find 3 as the least multiple (`2 * (1 + 1)` and `5 * (1 + 0)` were too large), so `Multipliers = {1, 1, 0}`.
- `index == 2`: we find 4 as the least multiple (`3 * (1 + 1)` and `5 * (1 + 0)`), `Multipliers = {2, 1, 0}`
- `index == 3`: we find 5, `Multipliers = {2, 1, 1}`
- `4`: we find 6, but `2 * (1 + 2) == 3 * (1 + 1)`, so `Multipliers = {3, 2, 1}`
- `5`: we find 8.
- Since `++index == 6`, index corresponded to value we want prior to the increment; return that value and we're done.

I wrote it up in code, if that helps:

```
vector<int> multipliers = vector<int>(lengthOfPrimes, 0);
// For duplicates:
vector<bool> isInMultiple = vector<bool>(multipliers.size(), false);
int index = 0;
while (index < k)
{
    int currentLeastMultiple = INT_MAX;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < multipliers.size(); ++i)
    {
        // check if the ith prime could have the next
        // least multiple of the array of primes.
        int multiple = primes[i] * (1 + multipliers[i]);
        if (multiple < currentLeastMultiple)
        {
            currentLeastMultiple = multiple;
            // reset our tracking of numbers equal to currentLeastMultiple,
            // since it changed
            isInMultiple = vector<bool>(multipliers.size(), false);
        }

        if (multiple == currentLeastMultiple)
        {
            // this tells us that 2 * 3 == 6 and 3 * 2 == 6,
            // so we need to increment multipliers for 2 and 3
            isInMultiple[i] = true; 
        }
    }


    if (++index == k)
    {
        return currentLeastMultiple;
    }

    // Update the multipliers that fit into the currentLeastMultiple
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < multipliers.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (isInMultiple[i])
        {
            multipliers[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```